# Database design guidance for 3 different users types

Tags: php, mysql, database-deadlocks

I am creating my first web application with mySQL & PHP and just looking for some guidance to ensure I'm on the right lines... or not.

It will have 3 types of user; `members`, `clubs` and `admins`.

I currently have them all logging in through the same log in page and once logged in they go to the same 'dashboard' but the content of the dashboard is changed via conditional statements against the users user type. Is this a sensible idea in terms of security etc?

My current simplified table structure is:

```
users   {id, username, hashed_password}
members {id, user_id, first_name, last_name, email, address, tel, cleared_activities}
clubs   {id, user_id, club_name, address, tel, available_activities}
admins  {id, user_id, first_name, last_name, email, address, tel}
```

Could this table design be improved upon? I'm conscious of the similar fields, especially amongst `members` and `admins` and this makes me think there is likely a better way.

Many Thanks

Comment: Move `first_name, last_name, email, address, tel` to `users` table? And remove `members` and `admins` - you don't want them

Comment: @DmitryTeplyakov would you say leave out first_name & last_name and keep them in the members and admins tables as a 'club' member doesn't have a first and last name but a club_name?

Comment: no. You can use only two tables - users and clubs. club member (and admin) will have first_name and last_name

Comment: @DanielGrander, and add `type` field to `users` table to know what type this user of

Comment: Like @codingstill says below ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all members and admins are users, I would use one table for user, members and admins adding one extra field "usertype".

Then I would add a table only for members, that would hold all extra fields that are member specific.

```
users       {id, username, hashed_password, first_name, last_name, email, address, tel, user_type}
member_data {user_id, cleared_activities}
clubs       {id, user_id, club_name, address, tel, available_activities}
```

If the extra member fields are just the one you mention, you could also keep it in the users table. For the users that are not of type member, this field will have NULL values.

```
users       {id, username, hashed_password, first_name, last_name, email, address, tel, user_type, cleared_activities}
clubs       {id, user_id, club_name, address, tel, available_activities}
```

Comment: the members table will in fact have more fields which are unique to members only, so your top solution would likely fit my situation better.

Comment: The top solution is better as a design, because it represents the objects of your applications more accurately. But for one or two extra fields, it is not much of a problem to put them in the 'users' table.